# How to show DataGrid header and footer row only when data is NOT EMPTY (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2008

I have seen numerous .NET solutions on how to show header and/or footer rows when grid returns NO  data.  I want to do the opposite, when data is returned (via sql stored procedure) then total each column in code behind and display totals in footer row BUT HIDE each row in between header and footer.  Why? because I haven't figured out how to (in SQL) sum, sums when parameters are used or else I would simply return the final sum in a single row and display one row in the grid. The better solution is probably re-writing my SQL query but in my limited understanding of advanced SQL I have opted to **sum DataGrid columns in code behind (not GridView) and display in footer, whilst hiding all rows except header and footer.**

So my question is, is it possible to total DataGrid columns, display totals in footer yet hide the other rows of data?

**SQL stored procedure**

```
    SELECT [EmpID]  
     , EmpName
     , tblCodes.CodeID 
     , [Timecode]
     , SUM(Hours) AS SumTotal 
     , SUM(CASE WHEN tblCodes.CodeID IN (4,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,17,20, 21,22,24,25,26) THEN Hours ELSE 0 end) as HOURS 
     , SUM(CASE WHEN  tblCodes.CodeID IN (5,23) THEN Hours ELSE 0 end) As SBY   
     , SUM(CASE WHEN tblCodes.CodeID IN (1,16)THEN Hours ELSE 0 end) As OT_CT   
     , SUM(CASE WHEN tblCodes.CodeID IN (3)THEN Hours ELSE 0 end) As OOL   
  FROM [TLS].[dbo].[vwTimeSummary]  

  JOIN tblCodes on vwTimeSummary.TimeCode = tblCodes.CodeName

  WHERE DayDate BETWEEN @StartDate  AND @StopDate

  GROUP BY
  ID,Emp, tblCodes.idsCodeID, Timecode

  HAVING
  EmpName = @EmpName
```

**.ASPX Datagrid**

```
<asp:datagrid id="dgdSumHours" runat="server" 
                            Width="250px" 
                            Height="91px" 
                            Font-Names="Tahoma, Arial"
                            Font-Size="Small" 
                            AutoGenerateColumns="False" Caption="Summary of Hours" ShowFooter="True">
                                <AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="#EBF5FF"></AlternatingItemStyle>
                                <headerStyle Font-Bold="True" HorizontalAlign="Center" BackColor="#333333" 
                                    ForeColor="White"></headerStyle>
                 <Columns>
                 <asp:BoundColumn DataField="HOURS" HeaderText="Hours" DataFormatString="{0:#.00}"></asp:BoundColumn>
                 <asp:BoundColumn DataField="SBY" HeaderText="Standby" DataFormatString="{0:#.00}"></asp:BoundColumn>
                 <asp:BoundColumn DataField="OT_CT" HeaderText="Over & Comp time" DataFormatString="{0:#.00}"></asp:BoundColumn>
                 <asp:BoundColumn DataField="OOL" HeaderText="Out of Level" DataFormatString="{0:#.00}"></asp:BoundColumn>

                    </Columns>  
                    </asp:datagrid>
```

**.ASPX.VB**

```
Protected Sub dgdSumHours_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridItemEventArgs) Handles dgdSumHours.ItemDataBound
        'public variables declared at top of class
        'dSumHours
        'dStandbyHrs
        'dOOLHrs
        'dOT_CTEHrs

        If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Or _
                                   e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then
            'sum all columns
            dSumHrs += Convert.ToDecimal(DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "HOURS"))
            dStandbyHrs += Convert.ToDecimal(DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "SBY"))
            dOOLHrs += Convert.ToDecimal(DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "OOL"))
            dOT_CTEHrs += Convert.ToDecimal(DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "OT_CT"))

        ElseIf e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Footer Then

            e.Item.Cells(0).Text = String.Format("{0:#,##0.00}", dSumHrs)
            e.Item.Cells(1).Text = String.Format("{0:#,##0.00}", dStandbyHrs)
            e.Item.Cells(2).Text = String.Format("{0:#,##0.00}", dOT_CTEHrs)
            e.Item.Cells(3).Text = String.Format("{0:#,##0.00}", dOOLHrs)

            dSumHrs = 0
            dStandbyHrs = 0
            dOOLHrs = 0
            dOT_CTEHrs = 0

        End If

    End Sub
```

UPDATE: Using CSS styles there is a way to hide rows and still be able to access the data in the rows from the code behind but it will leave a gap between header and footer rows where the hidden rows lie.  This is problematic if the data returns a lot of rows.

Apply this  CSS style:

```
.boundfield-hidden {
   display: none;}
```

to each boundcolumns' `ItemStyle-CssClassproperty=boundfield-hidden`

I would still like to know if someone has a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve the desired effect using a Do while loop to read through SqlDataReader  in the custom DataBinding event* for the DataGrid and passing these values to the global variables.  Then in the DataGrid's `_ItemDataBound` event, skipping over the routine to fetch totals if row is `.Item` or `.AlternatingItem`, and going straight to `.Footer` row to populate the cells in that row from global variables.

**Revised _ItemDataBound code:**

```
Protected Sub dgdSumHours_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridItemEventArgs) Handles dgdSumHours.ItemDataBound

'public variables declared at top of class
'dSumHrs
'dStandbyHrs
'dOOLHrs
'dOT_CTEHrs

If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Or _
                           e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then
    '** comment out this bit of code: *** sum all columns
    'dSumHrs += Convert.ToDecimal(DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "HOURS"))
    'dStandbyHrs += Convert.ToDecimal(DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "SBY"))
    'dOOLHrs += Convert.ToDecimal(DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "OOL"))
    'dOT_CTEHrs += Convert.ToDecimal(DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "OT_CT"))
ElseIf e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Footer Then

    e.Item.Cells(0).Text = String.Format("{0:#,##0.00}", dSumHrs)
    e.Item.Cells(1).Text = String.Format("{0:#,##0.00}", dStandbyHrs)
    e.Item.Cells(2).Text = String.Format("{0:#,##0.00}", dOT_CTEHrs)
    e.Item.Cells(3).Text = String.Format("{0:#,##0.00}", dOOLHrs)

    dSumHrs = 0
    dStandbyHrs = 0
    dOOLHrs = 0
    dOT_CTEHrs = 0

    End If

End Sub
```

***Custom DataBinding event:**

```
'Fill DataGrid, dgdEmpSumHours 
    Sub dgdEmpSumHours_BindData() 
        Try

            'connection
            Using cn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(cStr)
                'open connection
                cn.Open()

                'command
                Dim cmd As SqlClient.SqlCommand = New SqlClient.SqlCommand("storedprocedurename", conn)
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

                'pass input parameter
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmpName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddwnEmpList.SelectedValue  
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@BStartDate", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = PayPeriodBegDate()
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@StopDate", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = PayPeriodEndDate()

                'execute(Query)
                Dim reader As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)

                dgdEmpSumHours.DataSource = reader 

                If (reader.HasRows) Then

                    Do While (reader.Read())

                        If IsDBNull(reader.Item("HOURS")) Then
                            dSumHours = 0
                        Else
                            dSumHours += reader.Item("HOURS")
                        End If
                        '
                        If IsDBNull(reader.Item("SBY")) Then
                            dStandbyHrs = 0
                        Else
                            dStandbyHrs += reader.Item("SBY")
                        End If
                        '
                        If IsDBNull(reader.Item("OTCT")) Then
                            dOT_CTEHrs = 0
                        Else
                            dOT_CTEHrs += reader.Item("OTCT")
                        End If
                        '
                        If IsDBNull(reader.Item("OOL")) Then
                            dOOLHrs = 0
                        Else
                            dOOLHrs += reader.Item("OOL")
                        End If

                    Loop
                Else

                    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me, GetType(Page), "showalert", "alert('Oops, there is a problem displaying Summary of Hours table')", True)

                End If

                dgdEmpSumHours.DataBind() 

            End Using

        Catch ex As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException

            'message about exception here
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me, GetType(Page), "script", "alert('A SQL Exception occurred: ' + ex.Message + '.')", True) 

        End Try

    End Sub
```

Disclaimer: there may be typo's in this version of code in my effort to generi-size it.  It works correctly in my environment.